react setState mistake
have a mistake in a articles.js
articles.js:
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './index.css';

export default  class Class extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            asd: "asd"
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.df();
    }

    async df(){
        let a = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/articles")
        let content = await a.json();
        alert(content)
        this.setState(state=>{
           asd:content.core
            }
        )
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div id={"mainArticle"} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:this.state.asd}}>
                    </div>
                <div>
                    </div>
                <p></p>
                </div>
            );
        }
}

I take a string in the df function that contains an html fork and pass it to setState asd
after that, this function is passed to componentDidMount, which will launch the function and change the value of asd
next, the value of asd is passed to the
dangerouslySetInnerHTML attribute, where the div should already output the html markup inside itself
terminal gives me mistake:
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression
what wrong?
i dont no what to do...

This question is similar to: React: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The issue is in the df function's setState arrow function.
this.setState(state=>{
        asd:content.core
    }
)

It should either be
this.setState(state=> ({
        asd:content.core
    })
)

or
this.setState(state=> {
        return { asd:content.core }
    }
)

This is because if the function body starts with { after the arrow (=>), it gets parsed as a block body, instead of an exprerssion. Thus, it's like doing
this.setState(function (state) {
    asd:content.core
})

where asd: gets interpreted as a label, and content.core as an expression.
